# How can i touch image during animation? or am i able to touch it or not?

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview, touch

I am trying to touch the image during animation, and on touch i have to start another animation, but i am unable to touch the image during animation please guide me that am i able to touch image during animation or not? if not then what should i do to touch the animating image?

```
-(void)cheer{
      UIEvent *event;
      UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
      UIImageView *myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0 ,1024,80, 121)];
      [myImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"baloon.png"]];
      [self.view addSubview:myImageView];
      myImageView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
      [UIView animateWithDuration:10 delay:1 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
      [myImageView setCenter:CGPointMake(512, -1024)];

}
       completion:^(BOOL done){
         [UIView animateWithDuration:3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
          [myImageView setCenter:CGPointMake(512, -1100)];
                     }
       completion:^(BOOL done){
           NSLog(@"ended");                                                     
          }];
        }];
if (touch.view==myImageView) {
    NSLog(@"touched");
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

add `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction` to the animation options

also make sure `userInteractionEnabled` is YES on the image view

edit: it seems that you are testing for a touched view which is touched before an image view is created? that last if statement will never be entered. You create a nil event and then test if its view (which will be nil) is equal to the new view, this doesnt make sense. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: edited, i'm not sure what you are trying to do, but creating a new event wont work

Comment: i am animating a small image from bottom to top. now i want to make touch enable on this image during animation

Comment: the way i suggested first will work, but your touch detection won't

Comment: then what would i do when user touch the image?

Comment: you should either subclass UIImageView and override touchesBegan or add a gesture recognizer (this would be the simplest)

Comment: i did it but still its not getting touch!

Comment: add your updated code to the question and i can try to see whats wrong